# Remove XML text out of SQLite database

Tags: xml, sqlite

I have a .storedata db file. I can open this database file with sqlite3 and perform normal SQL operations on it. However, there appears to be XML data inside of columns when I query this database.

Is there anyway to remove this data (with sqlite preferably, or some other means) rather than parsing the XML myself?

Thanks

Comment: How are you pulling out your data?

Comment: The example you gave is not XML. Find out what it is and where it's coming from.

Comment: Define "remove the data".  Do you want to remove any rows in the database that contain XML data in this column.  Do you want to remove anything within the XML data in the column, leaving other data?  Or do you want to remove the tags but leave the contents of the XML?

Comment: I want to remove anything within the XML data in the column, leaving other data.